Неверный код подтверждения для тестового аккаунта телеграм
Не проходит авторизация в telegram-аккаунт с тестовым номером 99966-1-xxxx через собственный клиент, имеющий валидные api_id и api_hash.
Ошибка авторизации (библиотека telethon):
`"Please enter the code you received: Invalid code. Please try again."` 

Т.е. неверный код подтверждения. При этом, на запрос клиента вводится код 11111 (5 единиц) согласно правилам тестовых аккаунтов telegram, описанным в статье_1 и в статье_2.
Вместе с тем, в ходе регистрации и входа на клиенте телефона, данный код   работает.
В чем может быть проблема?
Код клиента:
client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), args.api_id, args.api_hash)

with client:
    session_str = client.session.save()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        try:
            client.send_code_request(args.phone_number)
        except PhoneNumberBannedError:
            print("Phone number is banned.")
            client.disconnect()
            status = 'banned'
    else:
        status = 'enabled'

    save_session_to_db(args.api_id, args.api_hash, args.phone_number, session_str, status)
    print(f"Session saved to database with status {status}.")


https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/developing/test-servers.html
